# Выдаёт ошибку в коде после get запроса

Tags: c#, get, proxy

В общем хотел сделать прокси чекер на c#. Информации о нормальных чекерах мало так что пришлось собирать её по кускам. В итоге в этой части кода (get запрос) выдаёт ошибку.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
string url;
var proxy = new WebProxy();
proxy.Address = new Uri("http://185.171.231.228:80");


WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.meow.org.uk/cgi-bin/env.pl");
req.Proxy = proxy;
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine (Out);

sr.Close();
```

Это из за строчки req.Proxy = proxy; Без неё всё работает нормально. Можете объяснить как пофиксить?

Comment: Может потому-что, прокси с данными параметрами недоступен или недоступен вообще!? Во-первых, такие вещи нужно оборачивать в try и смотреть что за ошибка, во-вторых, поднимите свой локальный прокси сервер и проверьте на нём, а не используйте первый попавшийся публичный прокси для проверки своего кода.

Comment: WebRequest устарел, используйте HttpClient